# Msg 512, Level 16 Error

Tags: sql-server

How can I solve the following problem?

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

I try to get the Frequency like:

```
| Frequency
| 19
| 23
```

But somehow I can't get more than I value by firing this Query:

```
SELECT ts.TimeDifference/ ts.EntryAmount as Frequency
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as EntryAmount,
    (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(d, t.minimum, t.maximum)
        FROM (SELECT max(Date) AS maximum, min(Date) AS minimum FROM Times GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
    ) AS TimeDifference
    FROM Times
) ts
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your innermost sub-select is returning more than one result. You are getting the min and max PER combination of columns 1, 2, 3, and 4. Get rid of the sub-select and it'll resolve the issue.

```
SELECT
   DATEDIFF(d, ts.minimum, ts.maximum)/ ts.EntryAmount as Frequency
   ,ts.column1, ts.column2, ts.column3, ts.column4
FROM
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as EntryAmount,
        max(Date) AS maximum,
        min(Date) AS minimum,
        column1, column2, column3, column4
    FROM Times
    GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) ts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate function :

```
SELECT ts.TimeDifference/ ts.EntryAmount as Frequency
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as EntryAmount,
    (
        SELECT Max(DATEDIFF(d, t.minimum, t.maximum))
        FROM (SELECT max(Date) AS maximum, min(Date) AS minimum FROM Times GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
    ) AS TimeDifference
    FROM Times
) ts
```